# Simulating a Copy Paste on a WebBrowser Control in Win Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control in a form with textual data and in that form I am introducing 2 buttons. One to copy the entire contents(CTRL+A, CTRL+C) and the other to copy only the selected (using a mouse) text i.e. only a CTRL+C and then paste it to a notepad.

Code for Copy: (this works partially correct. copies only upto a certain point)

```
this.WebBrowser.Document.Focus();
SendKeys.SendWait("^a");
SendKeys.SendWait("^a^c");
this.WebBrowser.Refresh();
```

Code for Copy Selected: (this does not work at all)

```
this.WebBrowser.Document.Focus();
SendKeys.SendWait("^c");
this.WebBrowser.Refresh();
```

Can you please tell me if this is the right way?

Answer (score 9):

Try this for Copy:

```
this.WebBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", False, vbNull)
```

Or
Use the property WebBrowser.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = True. This will enable the Context menu in the control from which you can Copy/Paste.

Comment: no this did not work for me! i do not want a context menu.. actually got to simulate using buttons only!

Comment: No it did not... i tried            this.WebBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null)
this.WebBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null).. only a part of the text is getting copied!!

Comment: also for copy of the text selected by mouse cursor i tried
this.WebBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null)... but this too din work... 

my control is webbrowsercontrol.. is it because of that?

Comment: I still am struggling wit this... can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Guys thank you so much for your replies. Ours is a windows based app which is hosted in web. The problem is because of this is what i was told. Thanks a ton!